# Set value of a row in a Pandas dataframe equal to that of a row in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, both have the same amount of columns and contain text data. The problem is that the data in the second dataframe is missing details:

```
   A        B 
1  Bob    Hoskins
2  Laura  Hogan
3  Tom    Jones

   A        B 
1  Bob      x
2  Bob      x
3  Bob      x
4  Laura    x
5  Laura    x
6  Tom      x
```

What is the fastest way in Pandas to set the value of the 'B' column in the second dataframe equal to its respective conditional value in the first? So any row where 'A' = 'Bob' will have 'B' set to Hoskins, Laura to Hogan and so on? The second dataframe is quite large as well, with 100,000 rows so a speedy solution is preferred.

Comment: Are the values actually 'x' and are interpreted as missing?

Comment: That was just a placeholder string I am using for the example, just assume its set to 'x'

Answer (score 3):

Perform a left `join` on the second df:

```
output = df2.merge(df1, how = "left", on = "A")
```

*** desired df: ***

```
       A        B
0    Bob  Hoskins
1    Bob  Hoskins
2    Bob  Hoskins
3  Laura    Hogan
4  Laura    Hogan
5    Tom    Jones
```

Comment: @GreenGodot let me know if this didn't work for you.

Comment: Hi, an issue with this approach is that I have since added one or two additional columns to the dataframe schema. These are just three unrelated columns that have the same values for both respective rows in both dataframes. When I run your code I get these columns duplicated twice (with _x and __ appended to their name). Is there a way to avoid this outside of pruning the dataframe afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `A` as index for the first data frame and then filter rows based on the index:

```
df.set_index('A').loc[df1.A].reset_index()

#       A         B
# 0   Bob   Hoskins
# 1   Bob   Hoskins
# 2   Bob   Hoskins
# 3 Laura     Hogan
# 4 Laura     Hogan
# 5   Tom     Jones
```